# Changing a path from a directory to a single input file

Tags: python

```
import os
path = 'c:\users\name\desktop\project\input_samples'

for xyz_file in os.listdir(path):
    if xyz_file.endswith('xyz'):
    (operations of function here)
```

In the folder 'input samples' I have multiple .xyz files (coordinate files). I'm trying to create a function that accepts a path to one input xyz file and not the directory.

I don't want it to loop over the files, just process a single file. I want to do it without having to remove all the files except 1 in the directory path, but i'm not sure how to redefine the function.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's [isfile](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path#os.path.isfile) and [isdir](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path#os.path.isdir) may help:

```
import os
path = r'c:\users\name\desktop\project\input_samples'

if os.path.isfile(path):
    # it's a file, do something with it
    pass

elif os.path.isdir(path):
    # it's a directory
    for xyz_file in os.listdir(path):
        if xyz_file.endswith('xyz'):
        # (operations of function here)
        pass

else:
    raise RuntimeError("Not supported entry")
```

Comment: Shouldn't the for xyz_file, if xyz_file and (operations of the function) lines go under the os.path.isfile(path) section?

Comment: No cause your path variable is a directory and not a file. It's checking if it's a directory first and then looping through the files in that dir.

Comment: @says it depends if you want to take care only for single file or handle the case where path is to parent directory only, so you have to scan files inside it

Comment: ok. I tried to run your code suggestion but got an 'expected an indented block' error, followed by an 'invalid syntax' error

Comment: @Samuel Sorry, I just saw your reply. I just want to take care of a single file

Comment: @says then just remove `elif` block